# Play Framework send array/list for client-side code to handle

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

I'm using Scala Play Framework 2.1 for my website.  I'd like to be able to pass an array or list to the client-side code for subsequent processing after the page is loaded.  The list is essentially a bunch of things to later request from the server.  My purpose is for the web page to be displaying data as it comes in.

The code below in a template works but it feels kludgy.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
<script>
    var items = [ @results.map{ res =>
        "@res.item",
    } ""]
</script>
```

Here's what I eventually want to do on the client-side:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
  var item = items[i]

  jQuery.ajaxQueue({
    url: "/dataJson",
    data: {item : item}
  }).done(function( data ) {
    addColumn(data)
  });
```

}

Comment: show us a snippet of the code you WANT to achieve finally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumming that `results.map(_.item)` is a list of strings:

```
@import play.api.libs.json._

<script>
    var items = @Html(Json.toJson(results.map(_.item)).toString);
</script>

//result: var items = ["a","b","c"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I used something similar:

```
<script>
  var items = new Array();
  @for((result: String, index) <- results.zipWithIndex) {
    items[@index] = "@result";
  }
</script>
```

But I agree that it's a bit kludgy, especially when you need to escape special chars...

```
// Multiline js escape can be done this way:
.replaceAll("\n", "\\\\\n")
```